# How do i use ThreadPoolExecutor submit with a function that yields in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, yield, threadpoolexecutor

I have the following code.

```
def foos(n):
    sleep(0.5)
    yield n

k = 8
futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as exc:
    for i in range(k):
        futures.append(exc.submit(foos, i))
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        for v in result:
            print(v)
```

This code currently prints sequentially with an interval of 0.5 secs. How do i concurrently pull the results?

Answer (score -1):

If you submit a function that returns a generator to the executor, then the result of the executor will be the generator. Thus, `sleep` will happen when you start consuming your generator.

For the sleep to be executed inside the threadpool, you need to consume your generator inside the threadpool. An option would be to transform your generator to a function that returns a list with the results from the generator:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep


def foos(n):
    sleep(0.5)
    yield n


def to_non_generator(func):
    def non_generator(*args, **kwargs):
        return [x for x in func(*args, **kwargs)]
    return non_generator


k = 8
futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as exc:
    for i in range(k):
        futures.append(exc.submit(to_non_generator(foos), i))
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        for v in result:
            print(v)
```